# mvc3/razor fractions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How do you write fractions in mvc3?!?

I know in php its `&frac12;`

I tried that and it didn't work.

General gist of what I am doing is just a simple site to list my movie collections, and one movie is titled `The Lion King 1 1/2` while another one is `Alien 2` which I also want to render as `&sup2;` in mvc3 but it doesn't handle these.

I am also making this site with WebMatrix.

Code:

```
@{
var mId = UrlData[0].AsInt();    
var db = Database.Open("PhotoGallery");
var movie = db.QuerySingle(@"SELECT * FROM Movies WHERE Id = @0", mId);
}
<h2 class="title">@movie.Title (@movie.Year)</h2>
```

Output:

```
The Lion King 1&frac12;
```

Comment: MVC does not get in the way of existing HTML mechanics, like `<sup>` tags and the `&sup2;` character.  What makes you think it doesn't handle them?

Comment: What i forgot to mention was i am saving the `&sup2;` to the `Title` field in the database along with the normal title and i called it with movie.Title and it doesn't format it.

Comment: `The Lion King 1&frac12;` is how it prints out. I'll edit my question and add my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you trying to write them out? If using @Model.Field try @Html.Raw(Model.Field) instead.

I wound recommend using the antixss libraries sanitizer first though before storing that data in the database to remove potentially malicious javasrcript

Comment: this is a local site only, and i am the only one with access to inserting any information into the database. I haven't tried anything except i tried to google `MVC3 Fraction Coding` but it returned 0 results for what i was looking for. I am kinda lost... Point me in the right direction with a link or something please :D still new to this code as well.